# What are good ways to take pictures of wooden furniture?

Tags: product-photography

Furniture is [our business](http://sourenfurniture.com/), both for inside the house as well as for gardens.
What should we to keep in mind while taking shots of chairs, tables and cupboards?

Comment: I find a (good!) polariser extremely helpful when taking photos of wooden objects. It can remove glare and emphasize the structure of the wood (which is what the material is about). Of course you can even use it to emphasize glare but I find that less than helpful in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is to make sure you compose the shot in such a way that someone can imagine sitting in it.  For like a marketing style photo, try having other things in the shot and have it set up so that it looks liveable, but keep in mind you want to design the scene so that everything is facing the camera.  Think typical theater design, nothing should have its back to the audience.

For individual product shots, traditional lighting and composition advice applies.  If you can get a large enough soft box it wouldn't hurt, but using traditional three point lighting with soft diffusers should work fine too.  Don't take photos straight on for most things, you want angles and curves to be nicely visible and to give it a 3d shape that has depth. Again, the goal is really to make someone feel like they could sit right in it/at it.  If they can picture themselves using it, they are more likely to want it.

Comment: Presumably this advice is specifically for chairs, not tables or cupboards. Or do you want the viewer sitting in the cupboards too? :)

Comment: @mattdm - only if they are an Indian... (ok, lame movie reference for 1000 Alex).  But yeah, for tables, having an angle that looks like someone could be sitting at it is still good though.  You want it at the angle it would be if people were sitting at it and you took a photo of them.  Cupboards, I don't have anything on though.